# How to write text on image in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible that we can write text on image using html or javascript.

I have done this

Created an em tag and create spans inside it and now we can write any text in spans and adjust the position of em tag such that it appears over image. Set the z-index of em tag to be larger value then image. Then it appears that text is written over image.

But I want to provide option using which a visitor can edit the text. How i can do it ?

Code Sample:-

```
$("#em1").html("<p><span>Hi I am</span><br>
<span> Trying to </span><br><br>
<span> To write text</span></p>");


#em1{
    display: block;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
    right: 145px;
    z-index : 10;
}
```

I am using a background (blank-nothing written on it) image

Comment: Add some code youve tried? that way we can help better

Comment: Use the image as a `background-image` for a `textarea`. But do you mean in a way that the text actually becomes part of the image??

Comment: You can to do it with contenteditable.

Comment: Can you add image in background using CSS.

Comment: @MrLister, @ dev did you actuelle read the question? He just needs something like contenteditable.

Comment: @BenniKa I did actually, but I'm not sure I like the OP's way to put a `p` in an `em`. Also I don't know which browsers the OP wants this to work in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `contenteditable` attribute on the `em` element. You probably need to inform users about the edibility, as people don’t normally expect it, and there is nothing in the visual appearance that suggests it.

Comment: Thanks for telling me this. Let me try and i will comeback with the result

Comment: Thanks Jukka K. Korpela. It works really very fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can have a textarea

`<textarea  class='abc' >Hello Boys</textarea>`

with some css applied to it.

`.abc{`

background: url('http://www.bzfusion.net/skymaps/sky_englishspring.jpg') no-repeat; 
background-color:red; 
width:300px;
    height:500px;
}​

Comment: Thanks sushil.I like the idea. This is also nice answer

Answer (score 0):

A good practice for this kind of feature is that drawing is done on server side. If you really need to draw on client, use HTML5 canvas.

If you will need to save that image, read this article:
http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

Comment: Please read the question again and than think about your answer. He said nothing of adding the text to the image, it is ok with just displaying the text above the image.